# Drive REST API + Shared File + "FileSize"?

Tags: rest, get, google-drive-api

We've noticed that when trying to GET a ***shared*** file (doesn't matter if you're sharing, or you're being shared with) using the REST API, the FileSize field is simply non-existent, which is actually rather troublesome for our usages.

We can certainly download the file via one of the various links in the response, and then detect the size, but that would require processing on our backend, and we'd much prefer to fail out (if need be) on our frontend before reaching that point.

Per the API documentation:

```
fileSize    long    The size of the file in bytes. This is only populated for files with content stored in Drive.
```

Are shared files not technically "stored" in Google Drive?

Thanks all!

-Cory

Comment: what is the mime type of the file? I ask because you say " various links in the response" which kinda suggests it's a Google doc/spreadsheet etc. Such files don't have a size because such a size has no real meaning since it can't be downloaded. It can be exported in a variety of formats, each of which has its own size.

Comment: Ah, that's correct -- all of the shared files in question are of a Google Doc/Spreadsheet type, and we make usage of the file.exportLinks object and pair it with the file.mimeType via a mapping.

Looks like we'll have to handle that ourselves. Thanks!